# How to redirect page rendered with React to other page when clicking on button with Python in Selenium?

Tags: python, reactjs, selenium, redirect, web-scraping

I am currently trying to **scrape** the content of a page, say it is called `https://example.com/home` . When I navigate on the browser on that page I am being redirected to this page `https://example.com/home/quiz` where I need to click on an button in order to exit that page and renavigate to `https://example.com/home`. I tried to reproduce that on my python code as shown below:

```
try:
    url = "https://example.com/home"
    driver.get(url)
    # execute script to scroll down the page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    time.sleep(10)
 
    #this page prints https://example.com/home/quiz
    print(driver.current_url)

    #button which redirects to https://example.com/home
    button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='course-placeholder']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a")
    print(button)
    # execute script to scroll down the page
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);var lenOfPage=document.body.scrollHeight;return lenOfPage;")
    time.sleep(10)  

    #get current page
    #this page prints also https://example.com/home/quiz
    print(driver.current_url)

except Exception as e: 
    print(e)
```

This is the structure of the `https://example.com/home/quiz` page which is rendered with React.js :

[image]

Does anyone understand why I cannot be redirected back to `https://example.com/home` after clicking on the button? I cannot figure out what is going on, any help would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance

Comment: you are not clicking the button, just getting the button element.

Answer (score 1):

Most possible, you forgot to add `click()` method to your button. Otherwise it can be about your selector.

```
 button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='course-placeholder']/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/a")
 button.click()
```

If above solution didn't solve your problem try following :

```
button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.overlay-close")
button.click()
```

Comment: You can't print `button.click()`... it's nothing. Printing `button` is going to print some ID for that particular element and be unreadable.